# Using UPDATE with an array - is it possible?

Tags: get, salesforce, visualforce, apex, dml

I have a controller with a variable that is output as an array - and I would like to use UPDATE to give my users the ability to make in-line edits to records displayed an a VF page.  Is this at all possible?

Here is my controller:

```
 public with sharing class QualOpController
{

public List <Opportunity> Opty {get;set;}
public list<String> campaigns {get;set;}

public PageReference saveOp(){
    UPDATE Opty;
    return null;
    }

 public String getName(){
        return 'QualOpController';
        }

public void load() 
{
  campaigns= new List<String>();
  Opty = [Select id, name, CreatedDate, StageName, Vert_Med__c, Company_Name__c, Next_Step__c, Vertical__c, Weeks_Live__c, Days_Since_Last_Modified__c, Contract_SENT__c, NextStep, LeadSource, Probability, Spend_Last_Week__c, Spend_Last_30_Days__c, Owner_Name__c, Revenue_All_Time__c from Opportunity WHERE Pipeline_Oppty__c = TRUE ]; 

  Set<String> campaignSet = new Set<String>();
  for (Opportunity j : Opty)
      campaignSet.add(j.Vert_Med__c);

      for (String campaign : campaignSet) 
      {
            campaigns.add(campaign);
      }
      campaigns.sort();
    }
}
```

I am trying to get:

```
 public PageReference saveOp(){
    UPDATE Opty;
    return null;
    }

 public String getName(){
        return 'QualOpController';
        }
```

To update records queried by:

```
campaigns= new List<String>();
  Opty = [Select id, name, CreatedDate, StageName, Vert_Med__c, Company_Name__c, Next_Step__c, Vertical__c, Weeks_Live__c, Days_Since_Last_Modified__c, Contract_SENT__c, NextStep, LeadSource, Probability, Spend_Last_Week__c, Spend_Last_30_Days__c, Owner_Name__c, Revenue_All_Time__c from Opportunity WHERE Pipeline_Oppty__c = TRUE ];
```

But the changes just won't save.

Is there anything I can do differently to make this work?

Thanks,

John

**EDIT** Here is the code for my page:

```
<apex:page controller="QualOpController" action="{!load}" showHeader="false">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SortableTable, 'sortableTable.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SortableTable, 'sortableTable.js')}"/>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>R2M PIPELINE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.GUIstyle)}" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Logo)}" alt="" /></a>       
            </div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="apex/GUIHome"><span>Gene</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/apex/HappeningNow"><span>Happening Now</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/apex/ClientDelivery"><span>Client Delivery</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/apex/MediaCash"><span>Media Cash</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/apex/ROIREVENUE"><span>ROI and Revenue</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="/apex/PRODUCTION"><span>Production</span></a></li>    
                <li><a href="/apex/SalesActivity"><span>Sales Activity</span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="/apex/PIPerformance"><span>PI Performance</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://na2.salesforce.com/"><span>Salesforce Home</span></a></li> 
            </ul>
  </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div class="about">
            <h1>R2M Pipeline</h1>
            <div>

           <c:PipelineNav />


 <apex:repeat value="{!campaigns}" var="camp">

    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="{!camp}" mode="inlineedit">
        <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed" width="1080" border="1" class="list sortable" >


                <tr class="headerRow">
                              <th style="background-color: #C6D4D4; color: #040404" width="100">
                        <b>Opportunity Name</b>
                    </th>
                    <th style="background-color: #C6D4D4; color: #040404" width="100">
                        <b>Company Name</b>
                    </th>
                    <th style="background-color: #C6D4D4; color: #040404" width="80">
                        <b>Contract Sent</b>


                    </th>
                     <th style="background-color: #C6D4D4; color: #040404" width="50">
                        <b>Days Idle</b>
                    </th>

                    <th style="background-color: #C6D4D4; color: #040404" width="70">
                        <b>Created</b>
                    </th>
        <th style="background-color: #C6D4D4; color: #040404" width="450">
                        <b>Next Step</b>
                    </th>

                    <th style="background-color: #C6D4D4; color: #040404" width="50">
                        <b><apex:commandLink reRender="button" onclick="window.open('/apex/Probability_Guide','','width=500,height=300')" id="button">Prob%</apex:commandLink></b>
                    </th>
                    <th style="background-color: #C6D4D4; color: #040404" width="100">
                        <b>Owner</b>
                    </th>
                    <th style="background-color: #C6D4D4; color: #040404" width="100">
                        <b>Stage</b>
                    </th>

                </tr>

                 <apex:repeat value="{!listOfOpty}" var="cs"> 

                  <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(camp=cs.Vert_Med__c,true,false)}" >

                      <tr class="dataRow even first" style="">

                            <td width="100">
                                <a href="https://na2.salesforce.com/{!cs.id}">{!cs.name}</a>
                            </td>  
                              <td width="100">
                                {!cs.Company_Name__c}
                            </td> 
                                <td width="80">

                               <apex:outputField value="{!cs.Contract_SENT__c}" >
                                     <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" />
                                </apex:outputField>
                            </td>


                            <td width="50">
                                {!cs.Days_Since_Last_Modified__c}
                            </td>
                            <td width="70">
                                 {!MONTH(DATEVALUE(cs.CreatedDate))}/{!DAY(DATEVALUE(cs.CreatedDate))}/{!YEAR(DATEVALUE(cs.CreatedDate))}
                            </td>

                            <td width="450">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!cs.Next_Step__c}" >
                                     <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" />
                                </apex:outputField>
                            </td>


                             <td width="50">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!cs.Probability}" >
                                     <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" />
                                </apex:outputField>
                            </td>
                            <td width="100">
                                {!cs.Owner_Name__c}
                            </td>
                            <td width="100">
                                {!cs.StageName}
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                      </apex:outputPanel>
                     </apex:repeat>

                     </table>

                     <apex:commandButton action="{!saveOp}" value="Update Opptys"/>  
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
            <br/>
  </apex:repeat>

                          </div>
            <div>

             </div>
            <div> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
         <div id="footer">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h3></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>                
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>           
                </div>      
                <div>
                    <h3></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>                
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>           
                </div>  
                <div>
                    <h3></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>                
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>           
                </div>  
                <div>
                    <h3></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>                
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>           
                </div>  
                <div>
                    <h3>Social</h3>
                    <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Ring2Media-INC/845391462194555" target="_blank">R2M Facebook</a>     
                    <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/ring2media" target="_blank">R2M Twitter</a>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div>
                            </div>
        </div>

    </body>            



</html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, I would suggest to ask questions about salesforce on **salesforce.stackexchange.com** - you'll get the answer way faster.
Secondly - your Opty List should be updated perfectly. I would suggest you to write it this way:

```
public PageReference saveOp(){
System.debug(Opty);
UPDATE Opty;
return null;
}
```

And after pressing "saveOp()" button check logs - whether the elements in collection changed or not. Most likely that the problem isn't in Update, since it doesn't give you an error. It would be also helpful if you post your VF page code.

Comment: Thanks @Azi - I will give that a try, I appreciate the advice!  It is so strange that it is not working!